# Defining The Range For Alphabets in C#

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, c#-2.0, ascii

I'm having trouble creating a marksheet program in C# 2.0, here is the code of it

```
Console.WriteLine("Prislogix Public School");
Console.WriteLine("\n\nMarksheet\n\n");
Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name : ");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Class : ");
string cls = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Roll Number : ");
int roll = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

This is the basic write and read task. What I want to create is a condition for name. For example, if a user enters 123 in the name field, it takes the name as 123.

I don't want it to allow any numbers in the name field.  How can this be done?
Do I have to define the range for ASCII Codes for alphabets? I think a do..while loop will be used but what how should I define range between alphabets (A To Z or a to z).

Answer (score 1):

You could do it simply like this:

```
if(!Regex.Matches(name, "^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
    // name is invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

Match against a regular expression:

```
if (!Regex.Match(name, "^([A-Za-z ]+)$").Success)
{
  // Error message here.
}
```

This will also allow spaces in people's names, which is probably something you want.

More about regular expressions in C# here: http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/news/csharp_0101.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(name, @"[A-Za-z]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
// Here we check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
{
...
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the combination of 'A-Za-z' and 'RegexOptions.IgnoreCase' is redundant. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx class and see if it matches your input.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple loop

```
string name = String.empty
do
{
  Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name : ");
  name = Console.ReadLine()
}
while(!Regex.Match(name, "^([A-Za-z ]+)$").Success);
```

Comment: its not working, in my visual studio c# 2005 the ANY class is not present

Comment: The question stated he was using Visual Studio 2005 (and thus C# 2.0), which does not support LINQ extension methods.

Comment: My bad. I missed that it was C#2. Answer updated apropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression. If they input invalid entry, reject the entry, display a message and request the input again. You could do all of that in 5 lines with a single while loop for each Console.ReadLine().

also:

```
int roll = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

int.Parse will cause an exception if the string contains any non-numerical characters.

Answer (score 0):

The most foolproof way, and probably the easiest besides, would be to run what the user has entered through a regex:

```
...
var validName = false;
 while (!validName)
 {
    if(!Regex.Match(name, "^[A-Za-z ]+$")
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid name; try again");
    else
      validName = true;
 }
...
```

Comment: i m using Visual Studio c# 2005 and in it Regex class is not present

Comment: You need to import the namespace in which it resides. Here's more details on the Regex class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the test is, that the string should not contain any digit (all other characters are allowed), you can use a regular expression:

```
var regExContainsDigit = new Regex(@"\d");

if (regExContainsDigit.IsMatch(name)) {
   // contains at least 1 digit
}
```

It becomes more complicated if a name is only allowed letters. Then you should also think about spaces, dots, letters with diacrits (ë é), etc.

Comment: Regex class is not present in my context

Comment: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

Answer (score 0):

```
string sPattern = "^[A-Za-z]+$"
bool isValid = false;
while(!isValid)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name : ");
   string name = Console.ReadLine();
   isValid = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(name, sPattern);
}
```

basically check the name value against regex until they get it right

Comment: Regex Class is not in my context

Comment: @Aliza: Did you actually try this? This should work. System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex is available in .NET 2.0.